# Is it possible to use a repetition structure in this code?

Tags: c, for-loop, repeat

What I want is to optimize this part of my code. It is just repeating itself but I don't know how to use a repetition structure here using the defines I used.

I defined the GPIO_Ports and Pins.
And this go forward until SEL8.

```
if (out & (1 << 0)) {
    GPIO_SetBits(SEL0_GPIO_Port, SEL0_Pin);
} else {
    GPIO_ResetBits(SEL0_GPIO_Port, SEL0_Pin);
}

if (out & (1 << 1)) {
    GPIO_SetBits(SEL1_GPIO_Port, SEL1_Pin);
} else {
    GPIO_ResetBits(SEL1_GPIO_Port, SEL1_Pin);
}

if (out & (1 << 2)) {
    GPIO_SetBits(SEL2_GPIO_Port, SEL2_Pin);
} else {
    GPIO_ResetBits(SEL2_GPIO_Port, SEL2_Pin);
}
```

Comment: Define arrays with the `SELx_GPIO_Port` and `SELx_Pin` elements, then iterate over them.

Comment: You mean like this: char SELx_GPIO_Port[9] = {SEL0_GPIO_Port, SEL1_GPIO_Port, SEL2_GPIO_Port, ...}
I am not sure if I did it correctly. Do I need to use ''? And what type is this array? char?

Comment: The same as the type of these symbols... Only you know them at this point.

Comment: Please show us what `SEL0_GPIO_Port`, `SEL0_Pin` etc. are, and show us the prototype of `GPIO_SetBits` and `GPIO_ResetBits`

Comment: @Eduardo and please show us the code you mention in your comment, otherwise it's hard to tell if it's correct. The type of the array `should is probably be `char`, but to be sure you need to answer my question in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know the types of variables used. The code could look something like this:

```
#include <assert.h>

// Indexas valid are from 0 to 8, some 9
#define IDX_MAX 9

typedef /* insert the type of SELx_GPIO_Port here */ gpio_port_type;

static gpio_port_type get_gpio_port_from_idx(size_t idx) {
  const gpio_port_type ports[] = {
    SEL0_GPIO_Port,
    SEL1_GPIO_Port,
    SEL2_GPIO_Port,
    SEL3_GPIO_Port,
    SEL4_GPIO_Port,
    SEL5_GPIO_Port,
    SEL6_GPIO_Port,
    SEL7_GPIO_Port,
    SEL8_GPIO_Port,
  };
  static_assert(IDX_MAX == sizeof(ports)/sizeof(*ports));
  assert(idx < sizeof(ports)/sizeof(*ports));
  return ports[idx];
}

typedef /* insert the type of SELx_Pin here */ pin_type ;

static pin_type get_sel_pin_from_idx(size_t idx) {
  const pin_type pins[] = {
    SEL0_Pin,
    SEL1_Pin,
    SEL2_Pin,
    SEL3_Pin,
    SEL4_Pin,
    SEL5_Pin,
    SEL6_Pin,
    SEL7_Pin,
    SEL8_Pin,
  };
  static_assert(IDX_MAX == sizeof(pins)/sizeof(*pins));
  assert(idx < sizeof(pins)/sizeof(*pins));
  return pins[idx];
}

void set_out(int out) {
   for (size_t i = 0; i < IDX_MAX; ++i) {
        (
           (out & (1 << i)) ? GPIO_SetBits : GPIO_ResetBits
        )(get_gpio_port_from_idx(i), get_gpio_pin_from_idx(i));
    }
}
```

The first two functions map a static index from the range of 0 to 8 to SELx_GPIO_Port and SELx_Pin variables respectively. After that the `set_out` function checks each bit in the input variable `int out` and calls the `GPIO_SetBits` or `GPIO_ResetBits` depending if the bit is set or unset. I used ternary operator, if the function would have different prototype, or are macros, you could just:

```
void set_out(int out) {
   for (size_t i = 0; i < IDX_MAX; ++i) {
        if (out & (1 << i)) {
            GPIO_SetBits(get_gpio_port_from_idx(i), get_gpio_pin_from_idx(i));
        } else {
            GPIO_ResetBits(get_gpio_port_from_idx(i), get_gpio_pin_from_idx(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What reason should one have to do what you suggest? (adding two tables and a loop) you can write that code just to get the compiler to unroll the loop, just because it has only three or four passes through it.  I'm not trying to avoid giving you the credit your answer deserves, but sometimes, it is better to say _Not, that's not possible, or desirable_ than trying to fight against it.  Even in cases where the PIC should have 30000 flags identified in a header file, it is no sense to write that piece of code.  And I don't downvote your answer, it seems to be correct.